# java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

My cassandra table columns in lower case like below

```
CREATE TABLE model_family_by_id(
  model_family_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  model_family text,
  create_date   date,
  last_update_date date,
  model_family_name text
);
```

my dataframe schema is like this

```
     root
               |-- MODEL_FAMILY_ID: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
               |-- MODEL_FAMILY: string (nullable = true)
               |-- CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
               |-- LAST_UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
               |-- MODEL_FAMILY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

So while insert into cassandra I am getting below error

```
tabException in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table sample_cbd.model_family_by_id: MODEL_FAMILY_ID, MODEL_FAMILY, CREATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, MODEL_FAMILY_NAME
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:44)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand [the source code](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/TableWriter.scala#L37), the Spark Connector wraps the columns in to the double quotes, so they become case-sensitive, and don't match to the names in the CQL definition.

You need to change schema of your DataFrame - either run the `withColumnRenamed` on it for every column, or use `select` with `alias` for every column.

Comment: sir thanks a lot . sir in a realworld project do I need to follow any procedure like Entity POJO kind of stuff in scala/spark , if so how to do it ?